$\rho_{X,Y}=1$ implies $Y-E[Y]$ is linear function of $X-E[X]$ with coefficient equals to $\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$

$\begin{align*}
&\rho=1 \\ 
\implies &E\big((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))\big)=\sqrt{E((X-E(X))^2)}\sqrt{E((Y-E(Y))^2)} \\
\implies & Y-E(Y)=a(X-E(X))
\end{align*}$

My hypothesis is that if $\rho=1$, then: $$Y-E(Y)=\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(X-E(X))=
\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\sigma_{X,Y}}(X-E(X))$$
Is this true? If so, is there a justification for that?
EDIT: Considering  $g(t)=E((X^*-tY^*)^2); X^*=X^-E[X];Y^*=Y^-E[Y]$ if  we have the equality in 'Cauchy-Schwarz' inequality, $\Delta^2=0$ and
\begin{align*}
&g\Big(\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{V(Y)}\Big)=0 \\ \implies & V\Big(X-\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{V(Y)}Y\Big)=0 \\ \underbrace{\implies}_{(\ast)}&P(X-\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{V(Y)}Y-( E[X]-\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{V(Y)}E(Y)=0)=1
\end{align*}
$\rightarrow P(X^*-\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{V(Y)}Y^*=0)=1$
$(\ast)$- By Chebyshev's inequality
And so, only if we had discrete random variables, I could say that the hypothetical equality was true.

Refer to Wikipedia for condition for equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

The equality here would mean that $(X-E(X)); (Y-E(Y))$ were linearly dependent?

Yes, that is correct.

Without loss of generality assume $E(X)=E(Y)=0.$ If $E(XY)=\sqrt{E(X^2)}\sqrt{E(Y^2)}$ then
$$E((X-Y)^2)=E(X^2)-2E(XY)+E(Y^2)=(\sqrt{E(X^2)}-\sqrt{E(Y^2)})^2=0$$ and therefore $\Pr(X-Y=0)=1.$

I'm sorry; why do we have the last equality before the conclusion?

Expand the square and use the hypothesis.
